# Can't get Category link inside get_posts

Tags: get-posts, categories

I created a simple function to display the latest posts.
Inside the function there is a conditional to display the post category. I found that to display the category name, using

```
$category = get_the_category($post->post_ID); 

$category[0]->cat_name; // I want to display only the first category
```

do the job, but can't find how to display the link to the category. Tried to use `get_category_link($post->post_ID)` but no changes, the link still redirects to the current page. The goal is to redirect to category archive.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add your code, It may help for everyone. By reading you question. By default normally that `get_category_link` is have to work. Just use `global $post` before your `loop`.  If is not work. What you have to do is.

1. Grab the category id using your `@category` variable. (you can use `print_r($category);` or `var_dump($category);` after your code `$category = get_the_category($post->post_ID);`)
2. Then use `get_category_link(pass your grabbed category id)`

I'm sure it will work.

For more info. Read this [CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link)

Comment: I am happy. This is work for you. Please can you vote up. :-D